# Minecraft and "World edit" "generate" command. Formatting for equations and how to use

Tags: math, shapes, equation, minecraft-fabric, minecraft-commands

I am aware that you can make a helix and many other shapes in Minecraft using an equation like:

```
//g -hc diamond_block rotate(x,z,pi*y/50); z/=2; x+=15; x^2+z^2<8^2
```

However I want to try and create a conical helix.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conical_spiral

And quite honestly I'm just not smart enough to figure out how to make the equation correctly to work in Minecraft.

Does anyone want to help me please?

I've scoured the internet for a few days and found a few half truths and solutions but .. *nothing works*.

It's essentially how to format and use the equation part: `(x,z,pi*y/50); z/=2; x+=15; x^2+z^2<8^2`

To match a conical helix or spiral (ideally  Fermat's spiral but I'm not fussy at this point)

Comment: Found this which helps but does not supply the answer: 
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/47384/how-to-construct-a-g-command-with-worldedit-in-minecraft[/link]